# How to use table values as parameters in stored procedure?

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, vba, stored-procedures

I would like to ask if I can use a table values as parameters in a **SQL** 2008 Stored Procedure.

```
spDeleteAE dbo.tbl_tmpAE.tmp_StoreCode, dbo.tbl_tmpAE.tmp_datetime
```

Can this be accepted in a stored proc?

Comment: Not exactly sure of what you want to do with the parameters. Maybe explain a little more clearly: what does the stored procedure do with the values? Are you just looking up a value to use as criteria in a WHERE clause?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use table as parameters you have to create a table type. It is explained here http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/passing-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/

If you want to pass existing tables in parameter to make requests in your stored procedure you could pass the names and use dynamic sql. See : http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/